# Delay network disconnection with Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell

I have developed a Powershell script to set my location in Skype for Business based on subnet of the network I am connected to. This is successfully running in a Windows Task Schedule upon connection of any network (**Log:** Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational **Source:** Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile **Event ID:** 10000)

If the network drops, or I sleep/hibernate/restart/or shutdown the PC, another Task Schedule runs  (same Log and Source, but with **ID:** 10001) with different arguments to clear the last location, but by the time it runs, the connection Skype for Business needs to publish my clearing of location is gone.

Is there a way with Task Scheduler to halt the disconnection of the network connection?

Comment: You might try to make the events that network drop/sleep/hibernate/restart/shutdown the OS trigger the event other than the `10001` or the `Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational`. The problem is those operations probably disconnect the network before to cause the `10001` is triggered so based on timing, have all those trigger the script instead and see what result you can get. Emulate a drop and find that event maybe with a disable of the network adapter or pull the cable. Would you consider testing with those events? I know ***some*** System power events: 1074, 6006, 6008, 12, 13, 109.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT - Thanks for the theories. Have already done searching before posting and came up empty. Need solutions.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT - Everything is a theory before it is tested. Fundamentals of science. My point was this a Question and Answer site, not a forum for discussing ideas.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT - There was no offense taken or intended. I am not looking for official answers here, for the reasons you specified, just possible solutions that have been tested as working to address the stated issue. Whatever Task Scheduler runs, does so in the context of the system, not Task Scheduler, hence I am not asking Task Scheduler to control the underlying system, I am looking for a way for the underlying system to have it's restart/shutdown/etc operations be augmented by additional steps that can be triggered by Task Scheduler, as this is what I am using to launch other code.